# Url Rewriting ASP.NET - Some images refuse to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have recently implemented UrlRewriter (http://urlrewriter.net) on my website and am having some issues.

I am implementing it so the page requests are extension-less. For example, `www.example.com/my-cool-product`, redirects to `www.example.com/Product.aspx?id=1`. This works fine.

The problem I am having is that, some of my site images are refusing to be served as static content. If I put the path to some of images on my site, they are served up right away (as static content), but some images try to route through the .NET pipeline.

For example, `www.example.com/Asset/Image/Image.png` returns a 404 as it is trying to hit up `www.example.com/Asset/Image/Default.aspx`.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening for some images and not for others?

Comment: One possible reason is that you do not use the correct relative path. But how can some one tell with out the real site whats the issue ?

Comment: I have not deployed this yet as it is development in progress.

Comment: The various rewrite rules may interfere with each other - if it's not too long, show us (all) the rules. Also, just to be sure, is it really `Asset` (singular form), or is your problem due to a typo and your folder is actually called `Assets` ?

Comment: @marapet Well spotted but it's not a typo :-)

I only have one rule at present:

<rewrite url="/home" to="/Default.aspx" />

Answer (score 1):

What version of IIS are you using? You may need:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

In your web.config `<system.webServer>` block

Or set a `<base>` url in your page head

Comment: I'm using IIS 7, and I have this in my web.config

Comment: I have basically followed Scott Gu's tutorial in 'Approach 3' [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: Are you using a `<base>` tag on your pages?

Comment: Yes, `<base>` means the browser will take the given url as a base for your images. So you could use `<base href="www.example.com">` and then all of your image links that begin with `/` will use this as their base, assuming image links are like `example.com/Asset/image/image.png` it should resolve the issue